# Attempting to set up an Active Directory Federated Service for Single Sign-On: getting error and need details on Activity ID

Tags: windows, active-directory, single-sign-on

Using the AD FS Management tool (v6.3.0.0) on Windows 2012 R2, I'm attempting to set up a single-sign-on for an ASP.NET page.

When the ASP.NET application launches the SSO web page, it says:

> An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information.

And it provides an Activity ID.

However, I'm not clear on where to find details of that Activity ID in any log file.

- The Windows Log File "Application and Services Logs > AD FS > Admin" doesn't contain it
- The normal Windows Event Logs don't have it
- I'm not seeing any "log" from within the AD FS Management tool

How can I trouble-shoot this (I'm definitely a novice with this tool)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question seems to be how to find more information based on the activity ID. If so, please edit your title to reflect this. If not, edit your title to reflect your actual question.

Comment: Most ADFS events are in the `security` log. There are debug and trace logs as well, but I’m not sure how to use them on 2012. Here’s an article on 2016: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-logging

Comment: @Appleoddity: many thanks, had already read that article and had already wished we were using Win 2016...it does seems that Microsoft have updated this area quite significantly.  You mention "security log", are you referring to the Windows Security Event Log?  If so, I cleared that and no messages are  written to that with the latest failure.